# Yii, importing library does not work

Tags: php, yii, identicon

i'm trying to implement [Identicon](https://github.com/yzalis/Identicon) library to my site but i get the error that class is not found.

i tried with `Yii::import('application.vendor.*');` so i put the library in vendor folder, but it does not work.

i also tried adding the library to the component controller but still gives me the error.

and i tried making the import in the view where the code will be

```
<?php
    Yii::import('application.vendor.*');
    $identicon = new Identicon;

    $identicon->displayImage('test');
?>
```

and yet it tells me the error that this class is not found. i just copied the src folder from the zip to vendors and components. how can i import this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally imported `Identicon` library by editing every file from the library and store it into components/Identicon.

it seems like the use of namespaces that each file had on the code wasn't allowing Yii to import, so it works by deleting the namespaces and the use command on every file, then import it in the config file.

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.components.Identicon.*'
),
```

**Note:** All files found in generator must be in the same folder that Identicon.php is place.

so you can use the library almost like the readme from `Identicon` says

```
$Identicon = new Identicon;

$identicon->displayImage('foo'); //Displays the image.
```

Answer (score 0):

if your folder structure is like

```
-- root
-- protected
      |---- vendors
            |---- myfolder
                     |---- MyClass.php
```

you can import it like this

```
 Yii::import('appplication.vendors.myfolder.MyClass');
```

since yiis auto load is based on file name, if class *Identicon* was defined in MyClass it wont get loaded because it has different file name, so in this case you have to go with:

```
 Yii::import('appplication.vendors.myfolder.*' , true);
```

Comment: sorry, but i tried both ways, on trying `Yii::import('application.vendor.Identicon.Identicon');` gives me "class not found" error. atleast it no longer gives me the "failed to open", im not sure if this has to do something with the library settings. ill check more about this

Comment: do you have some kind of caching mechanism? is apc installed?

Comment: i have it as vendor, and i dont think i have any cashing mechanism